# Delay when closing Tyrus WebSocket Sessions

Tags: java, websocket, tyrus

I'm building a service with Tyrus in Standalone Mode (Grizzly Server) where I send huge amounts of binary data via WS to a client. In my setup, the service is located behind a proxy server, so all data that is send, is first buffered at the proxy and after the proxy in the unix send buffer.

At a certain point in this transfer, I want to serverside close the connection. When i do so, the client gets the onClose event as soon as all the data waiting in the buffer and proxy is sent.

This behavior, where all messages are handled sequentiell and therefore the close message is the last one recieved by the client, is understandable.

But what I need is a way to close the WebSocket connection in realtime. Like the underlying TCP connection would close and therefor the client won't ever get the remaining data stored in the send buffer and proxy.

Does anyone got an idea how to create such an behavior with the Tyrus API?

Comment: This sounds like a proxy issue, not a Tyrus issue. If the proxy is keeping its WebSocket connection to the client open and continuing to send data, then the client should keep receiving it. If you have any control over the proxy, I would try to configure this buffer to be small. Look up bufferbloat to see why.

Comment: @mattm: A HTTP-Caching-Proxy should terminate the connection to the client as a soon as the Server sends his TCP Reset packet, or? So forcing Tyrus to not only queue a Websocket "close" command but actually terminate the underlaying TCP connection would solve this problem as well.

Comment: @lathspell I'm not sure about the proxy behavior, but yes, that sounds like a good suggestion.

Comment: Tyrus closes the connection after closeframe is sent. I don't think we can do anything else - seems like you'll need some custom "protocol" on top of what you are sending, something like a simple ack when all data is received and then you can call Session.close(..)